# IMAP archive on NAS storage forces a Error: Input/output error for maildir_lock

Tags: email, imap, sshfs, courier

My server is running out of hard disk space. The main reason is a huge amount of archived IMAP mails. Therefore my idea was to put all archived mails on my NAS and mount that folder on my server.

Here is my setup:

#### NAS - example.nas

```
popuser@nas:/root> id
uid=110(popuser) gid=31(popuser) groups=100(users),31(popuser)
```

A folder `/media/data/ARCHIVE/`, were the *popuser* has rw access.

#### Server - example.com

```
popuser@server:/$ id
uid=110(popuser) gid=31(popuser) groups=31(popuser)
```

The IMAP folder `/var/qmail/mailnames/example.com/info/Maildir/`, were the *popuser* has rw access.

#### sshfs mount

As *popuser* on the server, I created a folder called `.ARCHIVE` in the IMAP folder as the mounting endpoint. As *popuser* I am mounting the NAS folder as follows:

```
SRC=/media/data/ARCHIVE/
MNT=/var/qmail/mailnames/example.com/info/Maildir/.ARCHIVE/
sshfs -o allow_other -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null popuser@example.nas:$SRC $MNT;
```

As *popuser* I created the following IMAP folder structure:

```
mkdir -p $MNT/{cur,new,tmp}
```

As soon I click on ARCHIVE in thunderbird, I get the following error:

```
Oct  8 20:40:33 server imapd: Failed to create cache file: maildir_lock (info@example.com)
Oct  8 20:40:33 server imapd: Error: Input/output error
```

On the server, I can create/delete files within the mounted folder as *root* and as *popuser*.

I have no clue what forces the error.

Answer (score 3):

`sshfs` is an extremely poor choice for this because it doesn't offer a lot of the features "real" file systems give you, like reasonable locking. This is because it simulates a normal file system with a backend that can't handle all the requirements.

If you use a NAS, it can most likely handle NFS. Use this, it's a much better choice (and even then, you can run into a lot of trouble).

Comment: The NAS is in my local network and here I am using NFS quite a lot. I will try to tunnel NFS over SSH.

Comment: This sounds insane. Instead of this kind of frankenstein setup, consider if you really need access to the whole archive via IMAP or if you can setup e.g. a Thunderbird archive on the NAS or a local IMAP server in your network just for the archive. Bonus points for the real solution: Add disk space to the primary server.